# Ripple at Resonance?

Tags: filter, resonance

This parallel LC circuit, energized with a current source, is supposed to work as a low pass/high pass filter depending on the branch I take the output from. PSPICE simulation shows exactly that, EXCEPT there's a spike at resonance(157kHz) where the gain explodes. I did some googling and apparently this is what they call a ripple, am I correct? If so, why is there a ripple?

[image: parallel lc filter]

Comment: Your schematic is missing.

Comment: oops sorry:) fixed

Comment: Does your simulation model include any resistance? (Zero resistance (and no load impedance either) will give wildly unrealistic results for a circuit like this.)

Comment: Well it's a current source so there's an infinite output impedance. As for the model, no it does not include resistances unless specified. Why would it give unrealistic results? Is there any math behind it, or is it purely related to the 'modelling'?

Comment: gain=Q=2/zeta for dampening factor = Rp/ Xc(fo) and Rp= infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a filter, that's a resonant circuit.

As you've drawn it with ideal components, you would expect the impedance to become infinite at some frequency, 157k sounds right for those values.

With real components with loss, the impedance never becomes infinite, although it can become unexpectedly large.

A filter would be driven by a source with some resistance. That would 'tame' the resonance and give you more 'fliter-like' results. Look for filter design programs, there are a few free ones kicking about on the web. Simulate the networks they give, not forgetting the source and load resistance of course!

Comment: Agreed. The poster should replace the current source with a voltage source and a series resistance - 50 ohms would be a good standard value.

Comment: I added some parallel resistance so impedance wouldn't go to infinity at resonance. It worked, thanks.
Btw, if I wanted to pass this circuit as a filter, what changes would I need to make? Some sort of current receiver on the capacitor branch maybe?

Comment: @MdAjwaadZamanQuashef Look for filter design programs, there are a few free ones kicking about on the web. Simulate the networks they give, not forgetting the source and load resistance of course!